# LDA calculations manually

Tags: sentiment-analysis, lda

my question: has anyone ever done LDA calculations manually? I have difficulty in manual calculation. can someone help me to teach me for lda calculations manually.

Comment: I don't know what LDA computations you think about, but I have detailed the Fisher LDA [here](https://github.com/etiennedemontalivet/ML-tools/blob/master/dimensionality-reduction/Dimensionality%20reduction%20-%20PCA%20and%20LDA%20well-explained.ipynb)

Comment: Please detail what you tried sofar, and what LDA you are referring to so we can help